# PowerShell - Process multiple word docs (office 2010)

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, word-2010

I am trying to write a PowerShell script to perform steps on multiple Word docs. I have Word 2010 installed on my machine, but I can't seem to get the script to open the docs. Here is the script

```
    $path = "C:\MyPath" 
    Add-Type -AssemblyName Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word  
    $wordFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $path -include *.doc, *.docx -recurse 
    $objWord = New-Object -ComObject "word.application"
    $objWord.visible = $false 
    foreach($wd in $wordFiles) 
    { 
    $doc = $objWord.documents.open($wd.fullname) 
    #InsertProcessingFunctionsHere 
    $doc.Save() 
    $objWord.Documents.Close() 
    } 
    $objWord.Quit()
```

I try and run this, and the error I get back from PowerShell is:

```
    Exception calling "Open" with "1" argument(s): "Command failed"
    At C:\Scripts\Process-WordDocs.ps1:10 char:31
    + $doc = $objWord.documents.open <<<< ($wd.fullname)
        + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
        + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ComMethodTargetInvocation

    You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
    At C:\Scripts\Process-WordDocs.ps1:13 char:10
    + $doc.Save <<<< ()
        + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Save:String) [], RuntimeException
        + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

    Exception calling "Close" with "0" argument(s): "This method or property is not available because a document window is not active."
    At C:\Scripts\Process-WordDocs.ps1:14 char:25
    + $objWord.Documents.Close <<<< ()
        + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
        + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ComMethodTargetInvocation
```

MSDN states that documents.open only requires 1 argument, and the rest are optional. However, a C# example I have seen on the net, showed passing a "ReadOnly: False" parameter to documents.open. Stepping through the script in the ISE Debugger, I can see $wd.fullname is there and points to a valid file, so I am completely unclear why it is not opening. At first, I thought this was because I was using a 64-bit version of the OS (32-bit version of Office), but attempting the script from a 32-bit PowerShell Session resulted in the same error. Anyone have any insight here as to why this may be happening, and how I can fix it? I would prefer all the processing to happen invisible to the user. Any help would be *greatly* appreciated. Thank you in advance for your time.

Comment: The strange thing is testing this on a 64-bit machine that had Office 2007 installed on it, the script works. So it seems to be something specific to 2010. I'm hoping someone else out there has ran into this.

Answer (score 4):

I think you want to close the document using `$doc.close()` instead of     `$objWord.Documents.Close()`